# Weekend Date condition in SQL

Tags: sql, date

Recently I have been trying to select few values based on a date condition (in where clause).

example:

```
Select A, B, C, D from Table1 
Where D = TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(sysdate-1, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

However, there is challenge that our process runs on Weekdays. So above query fails when it is a Monday, as it checks for `sysdate -1` (i.e. Sunday) instead of Friday.
Also, the query will fail on holidays (say Independence day holiday).

How can I modify my query to handle these situation. Any help.. ?

Comment: How does it fail on the public holidays?

Comment: Also, which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: You need a calendar table that specifies valid working days for your organization.

Answer (score 0):

The dbms can tell you the weekday, but it doesn't know of your local holidays. So about your only option is to have a table with valid dates and use this (by selecting the max valid date before sysdate from it).

EDIT: Here is how to deal with weekdays:

Oracle's TO_CHAR can give you a day number, but whether this starts counting with Sunday or Monday depends on a  setting, so one better not uses this. But the function can also give you a day name for a language you state, so you can use that:

```
CASE to_char(sysdate, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')
  WHEN 'MON' THEN trunc(sysdate) - 3
  WHEN 'SUN' THEN trunc(sysdate) - 2
  ELSE            trunc(sysdate) - 1
END as weekday_before
```

Comment: and if I look for the weekend condition - is there any way to incorporate sydate-1(weekdays except monday) and sysdate-3(for monday) both ?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!.. But will it work in WHERE condition... SInce I have to fetch value from the table based on this date.. and hence this date condition should be in WHERE clause..